# How to display file path in a Spotfire DXP

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

i am using an excel file as a data table. how can I diplay the path of that file in text area(visualization), may be some ironpython scripting?

Answer (score -1):

To access the Data Table properties from within TIBCO Spotfire Professional, click on Edit > Data Table Properties.

Click on a Data Table and then select the ‘Source Information’ tab.

[image]

Comment: sorry may be the question wasn't clear enough. i modified it and hope it is more clear now. I know how to find the path but I need to display it in a text area(visualization). may be i need some iron python scripting. thank you for your response.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you need this to be dynamic text within text area ?

Comment: yes. if the path changes, i want it to be reflected in the text area.